# How can I return a Maybe value from do notation in PureScript?

Tags: option-type, purescript, do-notation

I'm trying to return a Maybe value from a function that uses do notation, but I can't seem to get it to work.  This function takes a string (The "filename") and a Path to search in...

```
findIn :: String -> Path -> Maybe Path
findIn search start = do
    file <- ls start
    if ((filename file) == search)
      then Just file
      else Nothing
```

Where...

```
ls :: Path -> Array Path
filename :: Path -> String
```

But I keep getting the error "Count not match Type Array with type Maybe", so it looks like the compiler is expecting the do notation to return an array.  How would I return a maybe value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix monads like that.

When you write:

```
file <- ls start
```

it's a bit like saying "for each value `file` in the array..." so you are in the context of multiple possible values.

But then the rest of the code is in the context of `Maybe`, which can only handle one (or zero) values.

In the module `Data.Foldable` there is a `find` function, which does the bulk of the work of your main function, by searching for a single item that matches some criteria. Its actual type is more general, but when constrained to Arrays it's like this:

```
find :: forall a. (a -> Boolean) -> Array a -> Maybe a
```

Then you can just write:

```
findIn search start = find (\x => x == search) $ ls start
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  So do notation has to return an array, and all the expressions are aimed at doing filtering and mapping on those arrays.

Comment: Yes that's right. If you want to return a `Maybe` then the `do` block needs to be all about `Maybe`. I've updated my answer a little.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  That note about being in the "context of Maybe" and in the "context of multiple possible values" make sense.  I haven't thought about it in that way before.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found something that works, but I'm not sure if it's ideal.

```
findIn :: String -> Path -> Maybe Path
findIn search start = if (length r == 1)
                      then head r
                      else Nothing
  where
    r = do
      file <- ls start
      guard $ (filename file) == search
      [file]
```

So it looks like the do-notation returns a value of type Array(Maybe Path) .